# Calling Mysql 5.6 stored procedure from mariadb client

Tags: c++, mysql, c, client, mariadb

Hi I have written some code for calling a stored procedure in a MySQL database using a MariaDB client, however the stmt->bind parameter is not being populated with the necessary MYSQL_BIND array for receiving the necessary data.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug with the driver?  Malloc'ing the data does not break the implementation, but MySQL has its own more efficient means of managing memory for these arrays than malloc.

If you are asking, I am using and abusing a switch statement, as I would like this function to be made eventually asynchronous in a cooroutine functor class working against a pool of connections, where a state value is used to control where we are in the switch statement.

```
//the function that does all the heavy lifting for persistence
xt::data::io::ret_val mysql_model::call_stored_proc(xt::data::model_factory& factory, 
                                                    const xt::object& obj, 
                                                    const xt::object* p_prev_obj, 
                                                    xt::data::io_call_back*& cb, 
                                                    const char* command)
{
    MYSQL *mysql = NULL;
    int state = 0;
    MYSQL_STMT* stmt = NULL;
    int status = 0;
    size_t parameter_length = 0;
    std::vector<MYSQL_BIND> ps_params;
    xt::data::io::ret_val ret = xt::data::io::io_success;


    xt::string sql("CALL ");
    xt::messaging::event_type type = xt::messaging::new_object;
    if(std::strcmp(command, "update") == 0)
    {
        sql += m_update_proc;
        type = xt::messaging::update_object;
    }
    else if(std::strcmp(command, "delete") == 0)
    {
        sql += m_delete_proc;
        type = xt::messaging::delete_object;
    }
    else
    {
        sql += m_insert_proc;
        assert(command == "insert");
    }

    sql += "(?";
    for(size_t i = 0;i < m_p_mem_row_set->get_field_handlers().size();i++)
    {
        sql += ",?";
    }
    sql += ")";


    switch(state)
    {
    case 0:
        mysql= mysql_init(NULL);
        if(!mysql_set_server_option(mysql, MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON))
        {
            show_error(mysql);
            return xt::data::io::io_exception;
        }
        if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql, m_server.data(),
                                m_user_name.data(),
                                m_password.data(),
                                m_schema.data(),
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                0))
        {
            LOG_ERROR3("Could not connect error(%s) [%s] \"%s\"", xt::longToString(mysql_errno(mysql)), mysql_sqlstate(mysql), mysql_error(mysql));
            ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
            break;
        }

        stmt = mysql_stmt_init(mysql);
        if(!stmt)
        {
            LOG_ERROR("Could not initialize statement\n");
            ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
            break;
        }
        stmt->bind = NULL;
        if(mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, sql.data(), (unsigned long)sql.size()))
        {
            LOG_ERROR3("Could not prepare statement error(%s) [%s] \"%s\"", xt::longToString(mysql_errno(mysql)), mysql_sqlstate(mysql), mysql_error(mysql));
            ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
            break;
        }
        parameter_length = m_p_mem_row_set->get_field_handlers().size() + 2;
        ps_params.resize(parameter_length);
        {
            xt::data::io::ret_val r = prepare_memset(ps_params, m_p_mem_row_set->get_field_handlers(), obj, command);
            if(r != xt::data::io::io_success)
            {
                ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
                break;
            }
        }
        //reuse params so offset from 1
        if(mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, &ps_params[1]))
        {
            LOG_ERROR2("Could not bind parameters error: %s (errno: %s)\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt), xt::longToString(mysql_stmt_errno(stmt)));
            ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
            break;
        }

        status = mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);
        if(status)
        {
            LOG_ERROR2("Could not execute stored procedure error: %s (errno: %s)\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt), xt::longToString(mysql_stmt_errno(stmt)));
            ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
            break;
        }

        {
            /* the column count is > 0 if there is a result set */
            /* 0 if the result is only the final status packet */
            int num_fields = mysql_stmt_field_count(stmt);

            if (num_fields > 0)
            {
                if(num_fields != parameter_length)
                {
                    LOG_ERROR("parameter fields do not match returned resultset");
                    ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
                    break;
                }

                //buffer to be a write target
                for(size_t i = 0;i < parameter_length;i++)
                {
                    if(ps_params[i].buffer_type == MYSQL_TYPE_STRING || ps_params[i].buffer_type == MYSQL_TYPE_DECIMAL)
                    {
                        ps_params[i].buffer = (char *) new char[ps_params[i].buffer_length + 1];
                        memset(ps_params[i].buffer, 0, ps_params[i].buffer_length + 1);
                        ps_params[i].length = new unsigned long;
                        *ps_params[i].length = ps_params[i].buffer_length;
                    }
                }

#pragma message("hack!!!!! bind not being allocated for stored proc")

                if (!(stmt->bind= (MYSQL_BIND *)malloc(stmt->field_count * sizeof(MYSQL_BIND))))
                {
    //              SET_CLIENT_STMT_ERROR(stmt, CR_OUT_OF_MEMORY, SQLSTATE_UNKNOWN, 0);
                    LOG_ERROR("Out of memory");
                    ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
                    break;
                }

                status = mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt, &ps_params[0]);
                if(status)
                {
                    LOG_ERROR2("Could not bind results error: %s (errno: %s)\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt), xt::longToString(mysql_stmt_errno(stmt)));
                    ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
                    break;
                }
                status = mysql_stmt_fetch(stmt);
                if (status == 1 || status == MYSQL_NO_DATA)
                {
                    LOG_ERROR("No data returned from stored proc");
                    ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
                    break;
                }
                else if(status)
                {
                    LOG_ERROR2("Error on fetching results error: %s (errno: %s)\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt), xt::longToString(mysql_stmt_errno(stmt)));
                    ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ret = (xt::data::io::ret_val) *((int *) ps_params[0].buffer);
                    if(ret != xt::data::io::io_success)
                    {
                        const char* error_message = ((char *) ps_params[1].buffer);
                        LOG_ERROR(error_message);
                        // dont break; we want to clean memory up regardless
                    }

                    //now clean up memory
                    delete ps_params[1].length;
                    ps_params[1].length = NULL;
                    delete [] ps_params[1].buffer;
                    ps_params[1].buffer = NULL;

                    for (int i = 2; i < parameter_length && ret == xt::data::io::io_success; ++i)
                    {
                        rowset_item* item = m_p_mem_row_set->get_field_handlers()[i - 2];
                        switch (ps_params[i].buffer_type)
                        {
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_STRING:
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_DECIMAL:
                            if(ret == xt::data::io::io_success)
                            {
                                ((rowset_item_string_t<char>&)*item).set_data(static_cast<char*>(ps_params[i].buffer), const_cast<xt::object*>(&obj), 0);
                            }
                            delete ps_params[i].length;
                            ps_params[i].length = NULL;
                            delete [] ps_params[i].buffer;
                            ps_params[i].buffer = NULL;
                            break;
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_DATE:
                            delete (DATE_STRUCT*)ps_params[i].buffer;
                            ps_params[i].buffer = NULL;
                            break;
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_TIME:
                            delete (TIME_STRUCT*)ps_params[i].buffer;
                            ps_params[i].buffer = NULL;
                            break;
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP:
                            delete (TIMESTAMP_STRUCT*)ps_params[i].buffer;
                            ps_params[i].buffer = NULL;
                            break;

                        case MYSQL_TYPE_TINY:
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_SHORT:
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_LONG:
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG:
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT:
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE:
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_BIT:
                            break;

                        case MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB:
                        case MYSQL_TYPE_VAR_STRING:
                        default:
                            LOG_ERROR1("unexpected type (%s)",xt::longToString(ps_params[i].buffer_type));
                            assert(false);
                            ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LOG_ERROR("no data returned from stored proc");
                assert(false);
                ret = xt::data::io::io_exception;
                break;
            }
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    if(stmt != NULL)
    {
        free(stmt->bind);
        mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
    }
    if(mysql != NULL)
    {
        mysql_close(mysql);
    }

    cb->on_model_request_complete(  ret,
                                    type,
                                    factory,
                                    *this,
                                    obj,
                                    p_prev_obj,
                                    true);
    cb = NULL;
    return ret;
}
```